# MFC icon works on Windows 7, not on Windows 8.1

Tags: c++, mfc, icons, taskbar

I have a MFC/C++ application that is built on a Windows 7 system, where it works fine, and I want to use it on a Windows 8.1 system. It also works on Windows 8.1, but the taskbar icon is the MFC default icon (3 blocks with "M", "F" and "C"), rather than the one I designed for the app.

My icon file includes 16 x 16, 32 x 32, 24 x 24, 32 x 32, 48 x 48, all in 4-bit, 8-bit and 32-bit color--BMP format, and 256 x 256, 32-bit color--PNG format.

The app is being built with Visual Studio 2010.

What do I need to do to get the taskbar (and other icons) to work on Windows 8.1 as well? I can't find any MS documentation on the icon requirements; a pointer to these would also be helpful.

UPDATE: When Windows 8.1 was rebooted, one of my icons appeared in the task bar (don't know which resolution or color depth), so, immediate problem solved. However, I'd still like to know why icon didn't appear immediately, and which format icon is used.

Comment: it isn't the application icon that is used in the taskbar - it is the main window icon.

Comment: I have the same question for all the types of icons an app uses; the one in the task bar, in the title bar, on the desktop, in Windows Explorer, etc.

Comment: Your icon file is input to the resource compiler, but apparently the resource compiler also takes an MFC icon from an MFC icon file. Why? The reason is probably in your resource script.

Comment: @MSalters: Interesting, but not what I asked. The executable icon is correct on Windows 7, but displays the default "MFC" icon on Windows 8.1. There should be some procedure for creating an icon for an MFC app that will work under Windows 8.1.

Comment: @Woody20: In case you didn't realize it: If Windows 8.1 would not have found that MFC icon in your program, it would by necessity have used the correct icon.